# replace rpm with yum while rpm using replacepkgs flag

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rpm, repository

I use the following rpm syntax in order to install few rpm' syntax that exist under pkgs

```
rpm -ivh --replacefiles --replacepkgs /home/pkgs/*.rpm
```

unfortunately in case of rpm dependencies rpm failed , so we want to use `yum` in order to solve dependencies

in order to use `yum` , what is the equivalent approach for the above rpm syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reinstall a package with yum is trivial:

```
yum reinstall <name>
```